# centralization of spring boot management endpoint url

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible in spring-boot application to create single management port/url of many application.

eg. in single instance we can do like below given property.

```
management.server.port=89090
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can implement it by creating management server of spirng-boot application for more details click on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-admin